# looking for a formula evaluated in Google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I'm looking for an add on in Google Sheets to help me evaluate formulas

Like the formula tab in Microsoft Excel, is there an option to evaluate the formula in Google sheet?